# getting updated timezone information in nodejs and types of libraries involved

Tags: node.js, timezone, momentjs, date-fns-tz

[With regard to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74753559/dealing-with-utc-dates-and-the-future) on how to manage timezone specific date as well as manage their conversions, I have been trying to think of a way to be able to get updated timezone information that reflects the latest possible data of the [iana tz db](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Since I'm using nodejs, my options was to use a library that dealt with timezones.
I found the following type of libraries, and I have queries related to each one:

1. That use the Intl api, and maintain/package no timezone information
   themselves(libraries include `date-fns-tz`, `day.js`):

   - First page of `date-fns-tz` says:

     > Time zone support for date-fns v2.0.0 using the Intl API. By using the browser API no time zone data needs to be included in code bundles. Modern browsers and Node.js all support the necessary features, and for those that don't a
   - As far as I can see, they dependent on nodejs itself managing the timezone data, which [in turn depends on the ICU library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477931/where-does-node-js-get-the-timezone-data-from), which doesn't seem to be updated quite often even though nodejs version itself gets updated. **Question a.**, is this a correct deduction, or do they query some external servers(user's system/remote etc)?
2. [Libraries that rollout their own compilation of tzdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone) (`moment-timezone`):
   They seem to update quite periodically, but, in the particular case of `moment-timezone`, it seems to be an addon for `moment`, but, they both seem to be legacy project, and [the homepage itself suggests not using it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment).

The best option for me would be the option number 2. But, as you can see above, I'd like to  avoid using a legacy project. So, my **Question b.** would be for a suggestion for a method to get the most updated timezone information for use in nodejs(possibly another library suggestion or something else)

Answer (score -1):

> So, my Question b. would be for a suggestion for a method to get the most updated timezone information for use in nodejs(possibly another library suggestion or something else)

I personally used moment for years but when it was classified as a legacy project, I switched to [dayjs](https://day.js.org/en/) with the [timezone](https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/timezone) plugin. Hope it helps

> Day.js supports time zone via the Internationalization API in supported environments. By using the native API, no extra bytes of timezone data need to be included in code bundle.
> The list of all time zone names can be fount in the IANA database.

Comment: hey, thanks for replying , but, my question stated confusion about the updated information of timezone that Intl api gave us (pt no 1, bullet 1 &2 ) above, that is something that dayjs is not clear on

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Doesn't _"using the native API"_ and **not** bundling the timezone data mean this doesn't actually meet the need?